# Do I have to delete the question if the problem was fixed in the next release?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question about a bug and possible workaround in Rails 3 beta. Now beta 2 is released and the bug is fixed.
Should I delete the question?
This particular question has no answers. Does it matter?
Thanks

Comment: No - if it was a full release of a product someone else might not have updated to the latest version yet and experience the problem, so leaving the question with the accepted answer being "upgrade" is the best solution.

Comment: As long as it says it's for BETA 1 in the title, I'd say keep it.

Comment: @beau Done. (concise but too short)

Comment: @chrisf I can't answer my own question and then accept it, right? So I keep waiting for an "upgrade" answer.

Comment: @art I think you can, you just have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: You can (or at least I think you can) answer your own question straight away (though in general it's polite to wait a while), but you do have to wait to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta releases are somewhat a grey area, but it's very well possible that someone else has the same problem with the beta version and is not planning to upgrade (or unable to).

And some software can stay beta for a long time. Yes Google, I'm looking at you!

Comment: I don't think being in beta or not is relevant to the amount of people who can potentially have the same problem. For example many people used gmail while it was in beta, many more than the ones that use software considered out of beta such as, let's say, putty (the SSH client). Going even further I believe the "beta" label to be completely useless and arbitrary, many beta softwares is more stable than release software.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just update the question to add the information you posted here.

Comment: I did (before posting here, just in case)

Comment: I was worried about breaking some rules. This downvoting thing is rather scary. Thanks for lending me support.

Comment: Oops... I probably messed up. I did what you said but accepted another answer. Is this okay? The other looked more authoritative to me. I don't know why. Oops! I'm leaving the third comment. Are there any limits on the number of comments? Don't answer, I'll check with FAQ.